# E:\project\node_modules\@floating-ui\core\dist\floating-ui.core.browser.min.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constantViolations')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am building a project using `React.js`.

I have an issue when building.
`npm run start` works well but `npm run build:production` doesn't work at all.

Here is my `package.json`.

```
{
    "name": "webApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "React Crypto Exchange setup",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-app-rewired start",
        "start:testnet": "env-cmd -f .env.testnet react-app-rewired start",
        "dev": "env-cmd -f .env.local react-app-rewired start",
        "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-app-rewired start",
        "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-app-rewired build&&cp build/index.html build/200.html",
        "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-app-rewired build&&cp build/index.html build/200.html",
        "build:testnet": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-app-rewired build&&cp build/index.html build/200.html",
        "build:surge": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-app-rewired build&&cp build/index.html build/200.html&& surge --project ./build --domain https://fanfury-test.surge.sh",
    },
    ... ... ...
}
```

When I run `npm run build:production`, I met an error like this, and the building failed.

```
TypeError: E:\temp\webapp-newui-webapp-winterupdate\node_modules\@floating-ui\core\dist\floating-ui.core.browser.min.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constantViolations')
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
```

I am not sure why this fails even though `npm run start` works properly.
Any comments and answers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in package.json below dependencies,

If using Yarn,

```
"resolutions": {
"@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "7.20.9"
},
```

If using npm,

```
 "overrides": {
"@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "7.20.5"
 }
```